# How to get the Value for <nobr> tag inside the td tag using javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays, sharepoint

I am trying the below code to get the values from td tag. I can get the My Name value but i am not able to store the date value which is inside nobr tag.

Below is my logical code.

```
var n = tableRow[t].getElementsByClassName("ms-vb2").length;

        for (var i=0, n; i < n; i++) 
        {       
          console.log(tableRow[t].getElementsByClassName("ms-vb2").item(i).firstChild.nodeValue);
        }

<tr>
<td class="ms-vb2"> My Name </td>
<td class="ms-vb2">
<nobr> 5/31/217 </nobr>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `textContent` and `innerText` properties.

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-vb2");
for (var i = 0, n = cells.length; i < n; i++) {
  var text = cells[i].textContent ? cells[i].textContent : cells[i].innerText;
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-vb2"> My Name </td>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
      <nobr> 5/31/217 </nobr>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that IE8 (as well as IE9, 10, and 11 when running in compatibility mode) will use `innerText`, while other browsers will use `textContent`.